# holding scroll position of a div tag as page refreshes

Tags: javascript

I have a div tag and I want to hold the scroll position even if the page is refreshed.How do i implement in JavaScript. Any help would be appreciated. Need just In IE.
Thanks

Comment: do you mean you want the div to stay in the same position relative to the screen, even if the page refreshes?

Comment: I want to maintain the previously scrolled div position  after postback/refresh.

Answer (score 0):

If the entire page refreshes,  you'll have to store the scroll position of the DIV in a cookie (or send/retrieve that position from the server, which is more trouble), then add a listener to the window.onload event that resets the DIV to the correct scroll position.

Comment: It would be great if you could throw me some axamples. thanks